# How can I make an HTTP request from an HTTPS website?

Tags: javascript, http, https, aws-lambda

I have a website which is on HTTPS, and I want to make a GET request to an HTTP port. At the moment when I try I get these errors:

```
cannot load ${url} due to access control checks.

this page was not allowed to display insecure content from ${http-url}
```

I have thought about putting the request in an AWS lambda function and calling the labmda function because that will give me an HTTPS URL? Is this possible.

Even so, I want to know what the easiest way of doing it is, as I don't know much about AWS so I would have to learn it.

```
const url = 'http://website/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-dbnames';

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function (params) { 
  console.log(xhttp.status); 
  if (xhttp.readyState ==4) { 
    if (xhttp.status == 200) { 
      console.log('===='); 
      console.log(xhttp.responseText); 
    } 
  } 
} 
xhttp.open("GET", url, true); 
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: could you post the code you use to create the request?

Comment: i think unsecure http requests will fail in most browsers due to the security policies. maybe this can help you, he uses a google tunnel to achieve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327314/how-to-allow-http-content-within-an-iframe-on-a-https-site

Comment: Can do a search for a third party proxy service that you send url to and it returns the data from that url

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn code is in the answer

Answer (score 6):

Well you can't browser will block any resources ( scripts , link , iframe , XMLHttpRequest, fetch ) to download if original html page is in https and request resources are in http.

Browser throws an `Mixed Content` error.

Snippet from Mozilla MDN

> Mixed active content is content that has access to all or parts of the
>   Document Object Model of the HTTPS page. This type of mixed content
>   can alter the behavior of the HTTPS page and potentially steal
>   sensitive data from the user. Hence, in addition to the risks
>   described for mixed display content above, mixed active content is
>   vulnerable to a few other attack vectors.
>
> In the mixed active content case, a man-in-the-middle attacker can
>   intercept the request for the HTTP content. The attacker can also
>   rewrite the response to include malicious JavaScript code. Malicious
>   active content can steal the user's credentials, acquire sensitive
>   data about the user, or attempt to install malware on the user's
>   system (by leveraging vulnerabilities in the browser or its plugins,
>   for example).
>
> The risk involved with mixed content does depend on the type of
>   website the user is visiting and how sensitive the data exposed to
>   that site may be. The webpage may have public data visible to the
>   world or private data visible only when authenticated. If the webpage
>   is public and has no sensitive data about the user, using mixed active
>   content still provides the attacker with the opportunity to redirect
>   the user to other HTTP pages and steal HTTP cookies from those sites.

Useful documentation links

MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content

Google developers - https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Ajax  calls as they are restricted by browser. You can safely use Server call with Server side Language like php node.js ,Asp.net etc